# How to populate gridview by comma splitted string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created Gridview like below lines of code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Jurisdiction">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJurisdiction" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseNumber" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have created a method in c# like below

```
private void FillJurisdictionGrid(string Jurisdiction)
{ 
    Jurisdiction = "Alaska, New York, Alabama";
    /* */ 
}
```

Now I want that gridview should be populated by string Jurisdiction. 
The above grid should appear as

- Checkbox1 - Alaska - texbox1
- Checkbox2 - Alabama - textbox2
- Checkbox3 - New York - textbox3

Please help me !!!

Comment: Convert your CSV data to `DataTable` or `List` and bind it to gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) function to split your data based on `,` delimiter. I hope `Jurisdiction` is coming as parameter in your method and in question you are showing it just for example purpose;

```
private void FillJurisdictionGrid(string Jurisdiction)
{ 
    Jurisdiction = "Alaska, New York, Alabama";
    string[] jurisdictionData = Jurisdiction.Split(',');
    grdView.DataSource = jurisdictionData;
    grdView.DataBind();
}
```

Finally simply add the `Text` attribute in your label:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lblJurisdiction" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```

Also, set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property in gridview to turn off the auto generation of columns:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

Comment: Very good solution... thanks a lot... Also there is one addition column which gets automatically appended in the last with the same  jurisdiction values with header text "Item"... can you please tell  how remove that one

Comment: @user2179026 - You're welcome and hey I forgot to mention, you need to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false. Updated answer.

Comment: What If I have two columns?

`strCollFinalized = "" + ddlContent.SelectedValue + "," + CheckInCollection(Convert.ToInt64(ddlContent.SelectedItem.Value)) + "";
   string[] strL = strCollFinalized.Split(',');
   gvData.DataSource = strL;
   gvData.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Jurisdiction = "Alaska, New York, Alabama";
string[] names = Jurisdiction.Split(',');
grdView.DataSource = names;
grdView.DataBind();
```